# This type of discrete dynamical system is special in some way?

Tags: recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

Please suppose that we have the 2D non-linear discrete dynamical system(or recurrence relations) $x_{n+1}=f(x_n,y_n)$ and $y_{n+1}=g(x_n,y_n)$ where $x_n, y_n \in \mathbb{R}$ .
Here, we know that the equation $f(y_{n+1},x_{n+1})=y_n$ and $g(y_{n+1},x_{n+1})=x_n$ are satisfied.($i.e.$ the inverse map of this system is given by interchanging variables and functions themselves)

Is this type of system is special or well-known? If so, please give me some reference and so on if possible.

Comment: Do you mean $y_{n+1} = g(x_n ,y_n)$?

Comment: Writing $\psi(x,y)=(g(x,y),f(x,y))=(y_{n+1},x_{n+1})$, we have $\psi² = Id$. I think with more contraint (continuity, derivability,...) on $f$ and $g$ you can find a reasonnable class of dynamical system.

Comment: Thank you!+1=(,) is correct.

Comment: and assuming that $f, g$ are $C^∞$ function of $x$ and $y$

Comment: Unfortunately the set of smooth involution is still pretty big. Some research on google will convince you to this

Comment: You can say that there is a fix point ( https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18192/fixed-points-of-continuous-involutions-of-the-plane ) . So a point such that $g(x,y)=x$ and $f(x,y) = y$.

Comment: OK! I try to search in google more.

Comment: and calculate fixed point.